# Vue3: watch() isn't called when it depends on a computed property which in turn depends on another property

Tags: vuejs3

**The setup:**
My router path is like so: http://localhost:8080/#/photos/%2Fdir1%2Fdir2%2Fdir3
[For clarity I am replacing the URI encoded values http://localhost:8080/#/photos//dir1/dir2/dir3]

**What I want:**

1. Get the value `"/photos/%2Fdir1%2Fdir2%2Fdir3"` into the variable `path`. I created a computed property, and it works
2. Get the value `"/dir1/dir2/dir3"` into `vpath` and this works too
3. Watch for changes to vpath. But, `watch()` isn't invoked!

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
// ... necessary imports go here!

const router = useRoute()

let path = computed(() => {
  return router.path.toString() // getting invoked
})


let vpath = computed(() => { // getting invoked
  return decodeURIComponent(path.value).replace(/^\\/photos\\//, '')
})


watch(vpath, (curVal, oldVal) => { // NOT invoked
  console.log(\`curVal = ${curVal}, oldVal=${oldVal}\`);
})
```

This looks fairly simple. Apparently, I am missing something.

What am I doing wrong?

I read https://www.thisdot.co/blog/vue-3-composition-api-watch-and-watcheffect and it looks like, based on the document, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I just found the answer: just tell watch() { immediate: true } and the watch will be called as soon as vpath gets the initial value (not just changes).

Like so:

```
watch(vpath, (curVal, oldVal) => { // NOW it's invoked
  console.log(\`curVal = ${curVal}, oldVal=${oldVal}\`);
}, { immediate: true} )
```